# How to insert function in element popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question can we add some function in popover bootstrap, 
im getting error and my code like this

```
  <li type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"
     data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" 
     value="Notification"/> 
<script> 
    $(function(){ 
    function myFunction(id){
    alert("Its Working"); }
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html: true, title: 'tittle',
    content:'<ul><li onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $id;?>)"></li>ID</ul>'});
    }) 
</script>
```

im already search but i cant found the problem that same with me

Comment: what kind of error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you adding onlclick event for the list element instead of adding 'onclick' handler directly in html, you can also have your id saved and restored easily using data-attribute

```
    $(function(){ 
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ 
        html: true, 
        title: 'title',
        content:'<ul><li class="clickable" data-id="<?php echo $id;?>">ID</li></ul>'
      });

      $('li.clickable').on('click', function(e) {
        var id = $(e.target).data('id');
        alert('This is working, id is '+id);
      });
    })
```